# New Angular project doesn't render properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I newly created new angular project and this is not render properly.

Instead of rendering default interface of newly created project this render views as below.

[image]

I have done all the codings correctly. Please anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: How is that not rendering correctly? This looks perfectly fine to me. If you were expecting the old, ugly default page just daying 'app works',, well, it's been replaced by this nice page since CLI 8.something. That **is** the default interface of a newly created project.

Comment: It's angular 8.3 Home page redesign. The home page of a newly generated project has completely changed, and it looks much nicer. It also includes helpful links to begin, and features some common commands.

Comment: This is as expected.  Theme changed since Angular 8. You can check rendering logic in app.components.html

Comment: They sure like to keep it fresh at Angular ☘️

Answer (score 1):

This is the default screen. Angular had changed their default screen.